# Estimating Interaction Variance for LMER Nested Designs

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I've read (e.g., [Schielzeth & Nakagawa, 2013](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00251.x) and elsewhere) that estimating and interpreting the variance for an interaction in a nested design is difficult because the interaction cluster variance pools the variance with the main effect of the nested factor. However, I cannot find any articles or discussion on how to appropriately account for this issue (if there is any way). Is there a way to accurately estimate the variance of the interaction only (via a linear mixed effects regression model or otherwise)? If not, is there a better/standard way to interpret such variance? Or are we left with just interpreting the interaction variance with caution?

Responses that answer the question(s) by pointing to additional scientific articles, tutorials, or statistical analyses are appreciated as well!

**EDIT**

Consider a slightly altered version of the canonical classes nested within schools example. If we add an assessment variable to the model whereby classes are each assessed two times per year on some outcome (say teaching efficacy), then we have a model with a nested interaction term (school X classroom) and a crossed interaction term (school X assessment, classroom X assessment). In `lme4` we can produce a random effects structure represented by:

- A main effect of school (`school`), classroom (`class_id`), and assessment, (`assess`)
- An interaction between classroom and assessment (`class_id:assess`), and school and assessment (`school:assess`)
- A nested interaction variable (which is related to my question), between school and classroom (`school:class_id`)
- The three-way interaction between school, classroom, and assessment (`school:class_id:assess`)

The question is related to the second to last bullet point (and perhaps the last). Since classroom is nested within school, from my understanding the interaction pools the variance between the interaction term and the nested factor (`class_id`), making the variance component for this interaction difficult to purely estimate and interpret.

For the sake of completion here is a reprex:

```
library(lme4)

df <- data.frame(
  score = runif(n = 200),
  school = rep(LETTERS[1:20], each = 10),
  class = rep(letters[1:5], each = 2, 20),
  assess = rep(c(1,2), 100)
)

df$class_id <- paste0(df$school,"_",df$class)

fit <- lmer(score ~ 1 +
              (1|school) +
              (1|class_id) +
              (1|asssess) +
              (1|class_id:assess) +
              (1|school:assess) +
              (1|school:class_id) + # nested interaction
              (1|school:class_id:assess)
              (),
            data = df,
            control = lmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa')
            )

VarCorr(fit)
```

Comment: Your question is too general. Please provide an example.